# button for selecting gender

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to have two image buttons one for men and one for women. when you select one of them, it becomes highlighted. i have written some parts of the code but i don't know what to to next. until now, **it doesn't change when you click the button.**
drawable/btn_selector_gender_men:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_man_active"   android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_man" />
 </selector>
```

i have set above code as the background of my button:

```
  <ImageButton android:id="@id/gender_man_button" android:background="@drawable/btn_selector_gender_men" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

another button same as above for women...

layout:

```
   <ImageButton android:id="@id/gender_woman_button" android:background="@drawable/btn_selector_gender_women" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <View android:background="@color/app_color_grayLight" android:layout_width="1.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="2.0dip" />
                        <ImageButton android:id="@id/gender_man_button" android:background="@drawable/btn_selector_gender_men" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: See this link http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html

Comment: Show your layout file code for your imagebuttons.

Comment: show your layout.xml code

Comment: Try below links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803430/how-to-change-background-image-of-button-when-clicked-focused http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125774/make-an-android-button-change-background-on-click-through-xml

Comment: On button click, change the background of the button that has been clicked.
You can do it by java code.

Comment: thanks for useful links. I set an on click listener and changed image Button's resources when clicked.