# Prevent Style Change of Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I initially set background of button with this code at `onCreateView`.

`uc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.saat_button_none);`

If I initially set background or textColor of button I want to prevent style change when I use `onClick`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bir:
            uc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.saat_button); //Should not work
            dort.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.saat_button_sel);
            bes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.saat_button_sel);
 }
}
```

Is that possible?

Edit: I don't want to use `if statement` since I have lots of buttons I just want to lock style of button.

Comment: If I initially set any parameter? what does it mean?

Comment: If I initially set background or textColor of button I mean

Comment: ok than what you want on button after click?

Comment: Change other buttons' background

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803430/how-to-change-background-image-of-button-when-clicked-focused)

Comment: @ilvthsgm updated the answer below, please review

Answer (score 1):

To do this, **create a custom view simply by extending** `View` **and override all methods related to background** and put your logic their if background has changed once then overridden method should `throw exception saying that you can't change the style as it has been changed while setup the default look and feel`.

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {
  boolean backgroundChanged = true;
  public CustomButton(Context context) {
      this(context, null);
  }

  public CustomButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public CustomButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override
  public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
      if(backgroundChanged){
          throw new RuntimeException("you can't change the style as it has been changed while setup the default look and feel");
      }
      super.setBackgroundResource(resid);
  }
}
```

At last in layout file replace `<Button` tag with `<CustomButton`